# In Opencart 2.1.0.2 customer profile photo upload option

Tags: opencart2.x

In Opencart 2.1.0.2, how to add customer profile photo upload option in customer edit profile page.

it is optional field only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a "Custom Field" for your customer, as there is no such field as a "customer profile photo".

Follow the steps in the screenshot as follows:

1. Click on "Custom Fields" in the "Customers" section
2. Name your field (e.g. "Profile image")
3. Select "Account" for "Location"
4. Set "Type" to "File"
5. Check the "Required" checkbox to make it mandatory
6. Also set its "Status" to "Enabled"
7. Setting "Sort Order" to "0" will pop the field up on top (first field of customer)
8. Save

Now

[image: OpenCart - Add a required customer profile image]

Comment: Glad my answer solved your problem. I would appreciate if you could mark my post as the correct answer. Thanks.